# Containment of dense subset

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following problem:

> Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space containing a finite dense subset $D$. Show that $X = D$.

I know I'm supposed to show my work or something, but honestly I don't know where to start. It seems obvious since $D$ is finite, but I'm not sure how to show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Indeed it is sort of obvious; but consider the smallest distance between the point that wouldn't be in $D$ but in $X$. What can you do with this distance?

---

Here's one solution: Suppose towards contradiction the existence of a point $x \in X \setminus D$, and let $\displaystyle \ell = \underset{y\in D}{\mathrm{min}}\ d(x, y)$, where $d$ is the metric operating in $X$. Since $D$ is finite, $\ell$ is well-defined. Thus we have that $D \cap B_r(x) = \emptyset$, which then implies that $D$ is not dense in $X$. Contradiction - there do not exist any $x \in X \setminus D$, so $X = D$.

Comment: Wow, I'm probably the most stupid person on this site. Thank you.

Comment: @NicoKonrad Don't worry, I'm sure you're not; these things just take time and practice :)